# debugger not working on browser dev tools after updating angular 8 to 15 dev tools

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, package.json, javascript-debugger

I've updated angular from version 8 to 15 and debugger is not working on any browser dev tools Can anyone suggest what am I missing is somthing wrong with source-map?

Here is package.json

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "~15.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/service-worker": "~8.0.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^7.4.0",
    "akbari-date-picker": "^3.0.5",
    "angular-toastify": "^1.0.3",
    "angular-toastr": "^2.1.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "highcharts": "^9.3.1",
    "mb-suites": "file:local_node_modules/mb-suites",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^5.5.0",
    "ngx-draggable-dom": "^2.1.2",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^10.0.1",
    "ngx-mask": "^11.1.5",
    "ngx-skeleton-loader": "^2.9.1",
    "ngx-virtual-scroller": "^4.0.3",
    "persian-tools2": "^1.5.0",
    "persianjs": "^0.4.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "react-toastify": "^7.0.3",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "sass-convert": "^0.5.2",
    "simple-keyboard": "^2.20.5",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "xlsx": "^0.17.4",
    "zone.js": "~0.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.1.4",
    "@angular/cli": "~15.1.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.5.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "^4.8.2"
  }
```

Here is package-lock.json

```
"dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "^15.1.0",
        "@angular/cdk": "~15.1.0",
        "@angular/common": "^15.1.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "^15.1.0",
        "@angular/core": "^15.1.0",
        "@angular/forms": "^15.1.0",
        "@angular/material": "^15.1.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.1.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.1.0",
        "@angular/router": "^15.1.0",
        "@angular/service-worker": "~8.0.0",
        "@ngrx/store": "^7.4.0",
        "akbari-date-picker": "^3.0.5",
        "angular-toastify": "^1.0.3",
        "angular-toastr": "^2.1.1",
        "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
        "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
        "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
        "highcharts": "^9.3.1",
        "mb-suites": "file:local_node_modules/mb-suites",
        "ngx-bootstrap": "^5.5.0",
        "ngx-draggable-dom": "^2.1.2",
        "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^10.0.1",
        "ngx-mask": "^11.1.5",
        "ngx-skeleton-loader": "^2.9.1",
        "ngx-virtual-scroller": "^4.0.3",
        "persian-tools2": "^1.5.0",
        "persianjs": "^0.4.0",
        "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
        "react-toastify": "^7.0.3",
        "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
        "sass-convert": "^0.5.2",
        "simple-keyboard": "^2.20.5",
        "tslib": "^2.3.0",
        "xlsx": "^0.17.4",
        "zone.js": "~0.12.0"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.1.4",
        "@angular/cli": "~15.1.4",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.1.0",
        "@angular/language-service": "~8.0.0",
        "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
        "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
        "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
        "jasmine-core": "~4.5.0",
        "karma": "~6.4.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
        "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
        "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
        "protractor": "~5.4.0",
        "tslint": "~5.15.0",
        "typescript": "^4.8.2"
      }
    },
```

I do expext to debugger hit the breakpiont.

Comment: Are you sure the code you're trying to debug is reached? What happen if you put a `debugger` in the constructor of your bootstrapped component?

Comment: @Jacopo Sciampi nothing happens debugger only works when I'm putting it into index.html file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So finally figured out what is going on; it appears that the project configuration was not migrated properly and fixed with this block of code in the angular.json file  *architect*>*build*>*options*>

```
 `"optimization": false,
  "sourceMap": true,
  "namedChunks": true,
  "extractLicenses": false,
  "vendorChunk": false,
  "buildOptimizer": false,`
```

Comment: could you explain why you use these parameters? and why angular works with them.

Comment: Sure, these parameters makes sure you run your angular app in development mode as you can see gives you namde chunks when you serve your app, but it's important not to use these parameters in build time because you don't want named chucks and typescript in build time you want your ts compiled to js